# Impedance matching of a transformer and reflected impedance

Tags: transformer

> Transformers are used to raise or lower the apparent impedance in
>   order to achieve maximum power transfer.

Above quote is from a tutorial I encountered with the following example circuit:

[image]

For the above circuit, what can we say about the transformer turns ratio or reflected impedance to obtain maximum power transfer? Do we need to know the frequency? What should be the way of thinking?

Comment: Maximum power transfer occurs when source and load impedances are matched.  A transformer reflects impedance as the turns ratio squared.  It will have a range of frequencies where it is useful, but for the purposes of this exercise you can assume that it's flat over the audio band.

Comment: 10:1 may give maximum power transfer but a terrible damping factor from the high source impedance.  Poor design. You need to know n=V(in/out) = Z(in/out) ², I negated the questions false assumption  for  an ideal criteria for an audio amp